How can I increase the number of concurrent requests Amazon SageMaker will take?
Bear with me here since I'm new to AWS. I'm trying to process this big database of documents, in particular I am using Mistral-7b-v0.3 to create summaries. I am deploying the model with this machine, using Real Time Inference:
instance_type = "ml.g5.2xlarge"
number_of_gpus = 1
health_check_timeout = 600
initial_instance_count = 5

I am using the endpoint from another big AWS machine (c6a.24xlarge) with a lot of processors (96). The problem is that when I try to use all the processors in parallel, the request just doesn't get to SageMaker. If I watch the CloudWatch there is no log to check.
Then, I've tried decreasing the amount of processors used from 96->15, and there it worked (but it didn't work with 16 processors).
My next thought was to increase the instance type and count to
instance_type = "ml.g5.4xlarge"
number_of_gpus = 1
health_check_timeout = 600
initial_instance_count = 10

but well I got a ResourceLimitExceeded error (with that instance type I can only have 2 instances). So I stuck with:
instance_type = "ml.g5.2xlarge"
number_of_gpus = 1
health_check_timeout = 600
initial_instance_count = 10

expecting to be able to use 30 processors instead of 15. But it wasn't the case, I could only use 15 still.
Anyway, is there anything to do to increase the request to the sagemaker? Any workaround or something possible?

(I'm assuming here you're using pre-built Mistral inference via SageMaker JumpStart?)
Batch Transform vs Real-Time Inference
If your goal is to process a batch of data one-off, then maybe SageMaker Batch Transform would be a better fit than real-time inference? With a BT job, SageMaker handles spinning up your inference instances, running the data through the instances, and automatically shutting down the instances as soon as the job is done. There are some caveats:

You still need to tune job parameters (e.g. max_concurrent_transforms per instance, max_payload if sending batched requests) to maximise throughput
Your input request payloads need to be prepared on S3 and your output will be loaded to S3 - so if your c6a.24xlarge instance is doing additional pre-processing or post-processing then that'll become separate steps before/after the job.
In my experience the CloudWatch logs from these jobs are not super clear for monitoring overall progress through the job... But perhaps you could query number of output objects created in S3 vs number of input objects, as an easy-to-check proxy if your job will take a long time? If trying to extrapolate ETA, note that it'll take several minutes at the start of the job to spin up the requested instances (just like creating an endpoint) - so you can't simply estimate by nItemsTotal * timeSoFar / nItemsDoneSoFar

...But at least with SageMaker handling the request queuing/batching, you wouldn't have to worry about whether it's the client instance multi-processing or the endpoint itself that's bottlenecking things? Even if the job would take a long time, you could shut down your c6a.24xl to save costs while you wait.
If you're interacting with SageMaker from the Python SDK, BT is handled by the Transformer class which you can create from e.g. model.transformer().
Instance types and Quota issues
As per EC2 instance types), g5.2xlarge and g5.4xlarge both have a single GPU - and 4 vs 8 vCPUs respectively. There are multiple ML inference servers out there and I'm not 100% sure which one the JumpStart Mistral container is based on, but I'm not surprised if 96 concurrent clients overwhelm 5*4=20 server processes.
You could try mini-batching your inference requests (so each InvokeEndpoint request has, say, 4 text prompts to analyze)? It might be that SageMaker's selected model server for Mistral is already able to do server-side batching, in which case this might not do much - but if they've not set that up it could be a significant improvement. Even if they have, it reduces the amount of magic the model server has to do on your behalf to get efficient throughput.
Consider that if you did scale up to e.g. g5.16xlarge (which has 32 vCPUs but still only 1 GPU), you might start running out of GPU capacity rather than CPU threads. This blog post has a bit of exploration about Mistral, but most of it seems to be Llama 2 oriented.
If bigger or more instances are what's needed, did you already try requesting an increase through the AWS Quotas console (check the Region if you follow through from this link)? If the AWS account itself is also brand new, it might be a bit trickier to get - but worth a shot if access to capacity is holding you up.
Note that real-time endpoints and batch transform carry separate quotas.

Thanks for the detailed info :). I'm not really sure if I can use BT because of the amount of data that I have (I think it might be to expensive to upload it to S3). However I did managed to make it work by using 6 instances of g5.12xlarge (4 gpus each). The problem that it gets stuck if too many request are sent at the same time (which is weird) is still there, but I fixed it by adding a random wait at the start of the process. This way the GPU kinda explodes but the requests are processed (or at least it throws an error)
